# Jackson Not Throwing Custom Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following field in my requisition

```
@NotNull
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @Schema(description = "BIRTH DATE", example = "1992-02-15")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
```

So I set up the following jackson deserializer:

```
public class LocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    protected LocalDateDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(
            final JsonParser jsonParser,
            final DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        String date = node.asText();

        try {
            return LocalDate.parse(date, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidDateFormatException("Invalid format" + date);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my custom exception class:

```
public class InvalidDateFormatException extends RuntimeException {
    public InvalidDateFormatException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This is my ApplicationExceptionHandler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    public static final String MISSING_HEADER_MESSAGE = "{0} header must be informed";

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidDateFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleInvalidDateFormatException(InvalidDateFormatException ex) {
        // Customize the response based on your needs
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**When I send the requisition with a birthDate wrong formatted the code enters in the deserializer, the exception is caught but the custom error is not thrown.** I just got a generic 400 like the image below:
[image]

I don't have any more clues about how to solve this problem.

Comment: It is not clear what happens. You say "the exception is caught but the custom error is not thrown", and the title is "Jackson Not Throwing Custom Exception", but are you really sure **this** is what really happens? Put some print into the exception constructor, or use the debugger. I suspect that the exception **is** *thrown*, but not caught by the error handler. Please verify it. And btw what is a "requisition"? Do you mean a request? :)

Comment: I have a quick theory, that you should use `@RestControllerAdvice` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html) and not just `@ControllerAdvice`. What is the Raw response? Is it some html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually solved my problem was to add the following config in bootstrap.yml:

```
jackson:
    deserialization:
      wrap-exceptions: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`@RestControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html) instead of `@ControllerAdvice`.

I believe that your code actually *does* throw the `InvalidDateFormatException`, but it is not handled later as you expect.

The title of your question probably should not be "Jackson Not Throwing Custom Exception", but "Rest Controller doesn't return error as JSON" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just I make few changes I hope to help you.

I created JacksonConfig, you can check I haved called your class here (**LocalDateDeserializer()**)

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
    import com.henry.stackoverflowdemo.exception.LocalDateDeserializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    import java.time.LocalDate;

    @Configuration
    public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

     
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

       
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

        return objectMapper;
    } }
```

So make public your constructor instead of protected

```
public LocalDateDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }
```

a few changes in ApplicationExceptionHandler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ InvalidDateFormatException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidDateFormatException(InvalidDateFormatException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), createHeader(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    private HttpHeaders createHeader() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        return headers;
    }
}
```

Remove **@JsonDeserialize**

```
@NotNull
    @Schema(description = "BIRTH DATE", example = "1992-02-15")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
```

I suppose you work with POST request in this case should be work.